# Inner join two tables and join count from a third table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 main tables - `posts` and `users`, and a third table that stores a user's favourited post as a row. I need to do a query on a post that is joined with the user data, and also whether or not the current user has favourited post (lookup in the `user_favs` table).

Ultimately I want to return something like the following to the client:

```
{
    post_id: '...',
    title: '...',
    user_id: '...',
    username: '...',
    isFavourited: isFaved > 0 ? true : false
}
```

Is this possible to do with 1 select query?

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    post_id    uuid,
    title      text
    author_id  uuid
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id   uuid,
    username  text
);

CREATE TABLE user_favs (
    user_id     uuid REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
    post_id  uuid REFERENCES posts ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

My query looks like:

```
SELECT
    p.post_id,
    p.title,
    u.user_id,
    u.username,

    count(f.*) as isfaved
FROM posts p
JOIN users u
ON p.author_id = u.user_id AND p.post_id = '1234'
LEFT JOIN user_favs f
ON f.user_id = p.author_id AND f.post_id = '1234'
```

and I've also tried:

```
SELECT
    p.post_id,
    p.title,
    u.user_id,
    u.username,
FROM posts p
JOIN users u
ON p.author_id = u.user_id AND p.post_id = '1234'
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM user_favs
) f ON f.user_id = p.author_id AND f.post_id = '1234'
```

EDIT: Just to clarify what I'm hoping to accomplish: I'm fetching a post, returning respective author of that post, and then also checking if the post is favorited by the requesting user.

Comment: You have many errors in your examples (i.e. `post_id  uuid REFERENCES users`). it is hard to read.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a user has favorited their own post, or if a user has favorited a post by *any* user?

Comment: The latter. So fetching a post, returning respective author of that post, and then also checking if the post is favorited by the requesting user. I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off bringing the select count(*) up into your SELECT clause similar to

```
SELECT
    p.post_id,
    p.title,
    u.user_id,
    u.username,
(SELECT count(*) FROM user_favs f where f.user_id = p.author_id AND f.post_id = p.post_id)
FROM posts p
JOIN users u
ON p.author_id = u.user_id AND p.post_id = '1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed the tables so i can test it. With the information you gave: 
Select for given post, the post information, the author and whether the current user (the logged user i guess) faved that post :

```
drop table if exists user_favs cascade;
drop table if exists posts cascade;
drop table if exists users cascade; 

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id   int primary key,
    username  text
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    post_id    int primary key,
    title      text,
    user_id  int references users
);


CREATE TABLE user_favs (
    user_id     int REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
    post_id  int REFERENCES posts ON DELETE CASCADE
);


SELECT
    p.post_id,
    p.title,
    u.user_id,
    u.username,

    case when f.user_id is not null then true else false end as isfaved
FROM posts p
JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN user_favs f on f.post_id = p.post_id
where p.post_id=1234 -- the post you want to select
and f.user_id = 4321; -- the id of the current user
```